# Why is Cucumber not executing my step definitions?

Tags: javascript, windows, cucumber

Working on Windows I have installed Ruby and the Ruby DevKit to get things working with Cucumber. Now I have the following basic setup:

```
/app
   /features
       example.feature
       /step_definitions
           example.steps.js
```

In the example.feature file I have:

```
Feature: This is an example feature
    In order to learn Cucumber
    As a developer
    I want to make this feature pass

    Scenario: wrote my first scenario
        Given a variable set to 1
        When I increment the variable by 2
        Then the variable should contain 3
```

And in the example.step.js file I have:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function () {
    this.givenNumber = 0;

    this.Given(/^a variable set to (\d+)$/, function(number, next) {
        this.givenNumber = parseInt(number);
        next();
    });

    this.When(/^I increment the variable by (\d+)$/, function (number, next) {
        this.givenNumber = this.givenNumber + parseInt(number);
        next();
    });

    this.Then(/^the variable should contain (\d+)$/, function (number, next) {
        if (this.givenNumber != number)
            throw(new Error("This test didn't pass, givenNumber is " + this.givenNumber + " expected 0"));
        next();
    });
};
```

Now, when I run 'cucumber' from the /app dir I keep getting the folowing output:

```
1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (3 undefined)
0m0.004s
```

I tried moving around the files, adding the --require option, etc. but nothing seems to be helping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this cannot be executed directly using the 'cucumber' command.
Settings things up using grunt and the [grunt-cucumber](https://github.com/s9tpepper/grunt-cucumber-js) task seems to be working as expected:

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        cucumberjs: {
            src: 'features',
            options: {
                steps: 'features/step_definitions',
                format: 'pretty'
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cucumber');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['cucumberjs']);
};
```

Additionally: if you are using protractor. It has cucumber build in. Just create the right config for protractor (protractor.conf.js):

```
exports.config = {

    specs: [
        //'e2e/features/*.feature'
        '**/*.feature'
    ],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

    framework: 'cucumber'
}
```